# Boost alternative to gsl_sf_legendre_sphPlm_array() for Legendre polynomials

Tags: c++, boost, gsl, polynomials

My understanding is that Boost library is much faster than GSL. I'm now maintaining a code that calls `gsl_sf_legendre_sphPlm_array` at some point in the calculation to compute Legendre polynomials. I was wondering: is there a Boost alternative to this function that performs sensibly better than the original GSL one?

Comment: I googled "boost legendre polynomial" and https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_poly/legendre.html was the first hit -- have you tried that, and if so, in what way was it inadequate?

Comment: Also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_math/legendre -- in std.  Is it that you want the coefficients, and these functions do the calculations?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont yes I read the documentation. The function gsl_sf_legendre_sphPlm_array automatically fills a matrix N_l^m (with 0<m<l) and I think it might do it in a smarter way than a double loop on l and m. It is not clear to me wether Boost does the same. The GSL function also takes care of the correct normalization, while Boost doesn't seem to do so. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: a) Are you sure that you can improve your performance in this way? GSL was built to guarantee reproducible results, I can't say the same about other libraries. 
b) According to the manual, this function is marked as deprecated. You probably should try the new one and see if this works for you.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: The standard library does not provide the ability to compute a Legendre series from a three-term recurrence. This is the main reason for anyone to compute a Legendre polynomial.

Comment: @Vladimir yes, I realized the function is deprecated. My plan was to check whether Boost was really performing much better than GSL and ponder a possible migration of the code. Unfortunately the Boost documentation on Legendre polynomials is rather poor and it is difficult to understand how to recover GSL results using Boost functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Legendre functions are simple, especially since they are implemented by a 3-term recurrence. Therefore, I do not expect boost to be any faster or slower than the GSL, especially for the evaluation of a Legendre series (say, using the boost `legendre_next`); they both should compile down to roughly the same assembly.

The reason to use boost or the GSL depends almost entirely on your environment.

One advantage of Boost is that it can be used in arbitrary precision; the cost is that you have to compile templates.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will keep using GSL then.

Comment: @SimoneBolognini: Strangely, I do not see any way to evaluate the three term recurrence in GSL; it only fills up an array. That's kinda weird to me. Anyway, if you do find out the relative performance of Boost and the GSL, then let me know.

Comment: My current problem with Boost is that the way in which the polynomials are normalized is not explicitly stated in the documentation. Therefore I'm having troubles to reproduce the GSL results. If I figure out how to correctly normalize the Boost results then I will do some performance tests and let you know!

Comment: @SimoneBolognini: It shows the Rodrigue's formula in the docs.